# How can I encode byte[] as ISO/IEC 8859-1 for efficient QR Code usage?

Tags: javascript, .net, unicode, qr-code, iso-8859-1

I have a byte[] that I need to embed in a QR code.  From what I can tell the only broadly adopted encoding is ISO/IEC 8859-1.

I think I can dust off [this old project of mine](http://baseanythingconvert.codeplex.com/) to map binary values, to the relevant ISO character.  I could then pass this to my favorite QR encoder and create the image.

Is this a reasonable approach?  Are there Javascript libraries to handle the decoding (reversing what the .NET project does)

Edit: Here is the data I must encode:

```
TOKEN {
"uidp":"c2FtcGxlIHJldm9jYXRpb24gaXNzdWVy",
"h":"BObbPeFd2XQZd7EJKhB1x\/Tdc2u9lcjpJYfhqa16z3yXSLFbzUurOV6\/83Tq499dhw6XEKFTBftmaQe+OXevwGk=",
"szp":"BBLJgzgFiJ0P8PUZdvCPlu8oyHYcCBpPkKKKlga33LOWOboLxQLf\/DBen2cDusWiifNwVEn5ev7Pr\/zEBZdoLis=",
"scp":"ctsCqIkJHAYw2qjlvzpE2HH0m8rOJTKJFv9RKPPMu6s=",
"srp":"QhSXSTgnaH\/WiON1YhvugklIgzl6aBprs1puVMMdJBc=","d":false}

Proof {"D":[],
"a":"v+YFX+Gtol8Fgt8acdz0hVNfa36o+PLo6Ybt7N6v6UI=",
"r":["JzYaNRnGm+c6cszvaCv3Y+bozepVV4EcVean+UxuApU=",
"h\/MfKC327MeZCKmzXeOYqsd2j6wGIlqV\/n+sNfg1z6o="],
"tc":["BJsQvPiycJs1yZQ6lFKd66vFV40HQ1jWOFEpSCfCxOt7bCxghSxk1JH\/Q7m0gaoXrJNxa8vvEyCJeB4DtWYXE2I="],
"ta":["m5n0MPSBhhvkc2sposGkKNswyc2XxAdqMGLBMd0w\/rU="],
"tr":["W31kbeJfFo\/cgvKBheCvuMioeFUsL5WWgImduanjTuo="]}
```

This is the additional, nice to have data

```
Revoke {"cPrime":"TJvtm1009we21ShdiUPg09HDzTHn9TOrraPikmvI3zg=","s":["SkYYaToNdf0u1y8XNxXsQRXQjx03WVcoxVzrcVkEUb0=",
 "7Fiv\/+Ng0W3ETul8J1aysgpVsZjV3xcofvatSM63Ztk=",
  "VGSTQNMrb24l0Rhak65iifo+ZpOFalqgXTu3yOj1AYc=",
  "oBUtiLsn+qBCyw\/aqX\/AT8z2L4f8Zp6Va8qZRARnWrQ=",
  "mrb4sl4\/2rCerZ5tuUJScU5T4t7xeoW\/T47pTEnsjvI=",
  "he\/CoGi3J4RNa3kRewC5xPIMZC5FzRDS8qQ\/5mbL2ck="],
 "X":"BCi71E75rtwbdD1Zp7VagxEizqoaYM9Dp6LhavuIMpQ5Uq07irgI7GGvynwlLipQ4\/QdBJ6JWHEUJfev6W9GNAg=",
 "Y":"BCusHw6YgL2naklMN7b6oxcKsN+dcPBecmwV0rwGAfSdvdvE5nwmUwkBMZTikJQeqlmTTak7Gb6StML4qOMRBgo=",
 "Cd":"BPC4kVkWttVK8tKvvAzC9Lj5UCWOXns+P8edkqPcSnmrqvxbZyG84KZ551hYZfveowufljA0QzJ3KzH+9Q\/kcHM="}


Escrow Proof

{"E1":"TQTbkHYPcY0aSf089n+\/phYGXB6iVaYHhc8biOW0U079Iae7X2pxC0lUsxnc4bY6bojd31tLgEi7UhNQ9w5T\/q3lA\/mrLE5iTw1odpt3q2nadw+1qfHNByj3Sxzj7jKXDOYm6xs7hqTPGyWY+KY\/ezQAvQnRKpRC8NNhLAw1zS+OPC1Xm0p\/G+rzTEXFx0JpeniAhbqWf59rXo0TeUgaP\/ZjJIhuD3dhtAKex0vY6rAZTsVqspcwFT3gdZEfZ78KNnVmZKdO4fPcP9zTlM5ahSGt+g+DkYblbYqupYTYhRBirPQi4DLo6EMUAwtgsNGVzgqVth4nGZxXu6pCsy8F0g==",
 "E2":"RXYDskBOiL7rY3EVrZflQfzbLHCNpbv0GSUWwnejYcKiZGF7r3fADIUegxqu+qZT5qPf+AnzBrhLIwalv65cjdotIKEsL+UYLWTPBlpFB\/SI9tJuIoncnZARHgh7kveXtV0yELsbP0kc9LvYssj0CTMC98\/oLBSwdeSbCXyIdN5lFjqi0w1q355yhKFo5Cu\/2WrpGf6jvFZbWmvrv2XJ\/g0F6Eqec2akaWAQ8GXHooXs2sF2WZqU+fWIJaB6AQfz\/oDca4BZZn4cWQe6Wv1v6gTE8mbgUJFrEk8ZGmqEOrVhl4Zyqe\/P\/5SJVyZOlOFXH8ksIfwSPZORn0x+8rCstw==",
 "info":"PGRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIG9mIHRoZSBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi1zcGVjaWZpYyBhdWRpdG9yIGRlY3J5cHRpb24gcG9saWN5Pg==",
 "ieproof":{"c":"MzaaPCT+rhHMQTDgqHvsrPNQZmdYKgynNLC8Cr8od7c=",
 "rXb":"Sy5Cwnv0CORlmzzftxuTZFPuhOOJpovHgom9+rxyrG8=",
 "rR":"nhukStQ\/L9+PS\/dkGkZWOdArizf2RSJwnmrQrFDRd00=",
 "rOb":"XqhIQPxLS4eGsrFmrJ93UkR4u7eIyNPpEnv9MIAuz+U="}}
```

Comment: Does the `byte[]` contain arbitrary binary data? If it's not *actually* ISO-8859-1 text, then decoding it as that could end up with unprintable characters etc...

Comment: @JonSkeet The `byte[]` contains encryption key data: a FieldZqElement: an element in a prime field and other data types currently encoded as Base64.  I intend javascript to read this data and make use of it in a human friendly form.  (e.g. decrypting a message, etc)

Comment: If it's an encryption key in a raw binary form, then base64 would be sensible, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet In this experiment I'm really trying to push the boundaries of QR codes.  I edited the Q to include the massive amount of data the is required/optional in a session.  I looking at the 8859-1 character list, and think that whatever isn't included in Base64 would be the % more data I could shoehorn into a QR

Comment: Well it would give you 4/3 times as much data, as base64 encodes 3 bytes in 4 characters.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, just to clarify, I'm not planning on going `byte[]` -> Base64 (with padding) -> 8859-1 ... A QR code already has some error correction built in, so I'll just go byte[] to 8859-1 unless you have a better suggestion

Comment: You do know that QR codes support binary data, don't you?  You don't have to encode the `byte[]` data as anything, put it in the QR code as-is, and then set the data's 4-bit indicator to `Byte` encoding (`0100`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Maybe this is a quirk with Telerik, what library do you use for `byte[]`?  (no I didn't know, I read the Wiki page and since it was geared for the Automobile industry, I thought that data feature never caught on)

Comment: @makerofthings7: I don't use QR codes myself, I was referring to information [documented on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) and the [QR Code spec](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/standards.html). Of course, standard QR readers are going to interpret `Byte` data as ISO-8859-1 text, but if you are writing your own reader then you can interpret the data any way you wish.